# Using BigQuery Storage API for small but frequent queries

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I'm building a service that needs to frequently read from BigQuery with statements like `SELECT foo FROM my-table WHERE bar = ?` where results don't exceed 1 row. Recently read about [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/libraries) that allows for faster access. My understanding is that the API use RPC streams and allows for parallelism between consumers.

Not sure if BigQuery Storage API is appropriate for this case as I'd like to take advantage of it to improve the performance of my service. i.e. I'd need to frequently send queries over the stream and retrieve results. Is this doable? If so, I can't find documentations on how to do this. The [examples](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage#samples) mentions nothing about it.